# $_POST["variable"] in PHP is not remembered in all the pages in my project

Tags: php, post

I am having 3 pages : page1.php , page2.php , page3.php . page1.php is a registration form and the action of the form is page2.php in page2.php I simply want to display the entered value of the registration form in page1.php so I type:

[image]

As you see in page2.php I have an  tag which makes you go to page3.php in page3.php I have this code:

http://s28.postimg.org/4fruiudt7/Page3.jpg

but it gives me the following error messages:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\page3.php on line 3
>   Username: 
>   Notice: Undefined index: passwd in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\page3.php on line 4
>   Password:

My question is: **how to make the page3.php remember the `$_POST` variables.**

And how to make the rest of php files in the directory of page1.php , page2.php , page3.php remember the values of the $_POST variable too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should be using $_SESSION for this kind of stuff. You can assign a value to it, and it will be remembered. I think the problem with your current script is that you do not "post" to page3.php via forms, therefore PHP won't find anything in those variables.

Comment: So how do you suggest to change my code to remember the values in page3.php and in all the pages of the same directory.

Comment: Can't see your original code right now, but it should be like this: `SESSION_START() $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` and afterwards reference `$_SESSION['username']` instead of it's $_POST equivalent. When you are finished, you can unset the values and destroy the session. You can read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: And how do I destroy the the sesion variables and the session afterwards ?

Comment: for example: `session_destroy();` but you can see more on the link above. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Every page in your application doesn't remember `$_POST`, that's not how it works. When you post to a page using a form, then the data posted to that page is available using `$_POST`. When you then go to another page, this data is not posted to it. You should use `$_SESSION` if you want to remember data between pages.